# How to detect checkbox state in Javascript IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, checkbox

I have a simple checkbox on my website.  Everytime you check and uncheck it, it shows an alert as to what the state is.  This works flawlessly in FF, Chrome, and IE8.  However, when I run this in IE7, no matter if the check is on or off, it always alerts "off".  It's like IE7 can't detect that the checkbox is checked.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this or work around it?  I basically need to toggle the visibility of some content based on a checkbox, but IE7 is being difficult.  Thanks!

Here is my code that I'm using:

```
function showHideTimeDropdown()  
{   
  if (document.getElementById("input_checkbox").checked == true){
    alert("on");
  }
  else{  
    alert("off");  
  }  
}
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, turns out that having the Name and the ID of the element confused the browser.  I made the name of the element different than the ID and that solved it.

Thank you both for helping me out.  Just hearing that you guys had tried it and couldn't replicate my problem told me that perhaps I was looking in the wrong place, of which I was :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, turns out that having both the Name and the ID of the element the same confused the browser. I made the name of the element different than the ID and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i wanted to help but I was unable to duplicate the problem..  below is the code I tried.

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <script language="javascript"> 
  function showHideTimeDropdown()   
{    
  if (document.getElementById("input_checkbox").checked == true){ 
    alert("on"); 
  } 
  else{   
    alert("off");   
  }   
} 
window.onload = function () {showHideTimeDropdown();};
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 


<input id="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" onchange="showHideTimeDropdown();">
<input type=text>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works in IE7. Perhaps you can post the code for the checkbox and for whatever event handler calls the "showHideTimeDropdown" function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function showHideTimeDropdown()  
      {
        if (document.getElementById("input_checkbox").checked)
          alert("on");
        else
          alert("off");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input onclick="showHideTimeDropdown();" id="input_checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
  </body>
</html>
```